# Simple ASK CLI install in windows not working

Tags: npm, alexa-skills-kit, ask-cli

I installed in Windows 10 ASK CLI with

```
npm install -g ask-cli
```

without errors.

But the next step

```
ask new
```

results in the error:

```
Invalid json: C:\Users\user1\.ask\cli_config
```

Sure, the folder

```
C:\Users\user1\.ask
```

doesn't exist.

Is there something fundamentally wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You haven't initialized the CLI with `ask init` which is the step that will ultimately generate the cli config file. Please read the installation docs again!

Answer (score 2):

ASK CLI v2 replaces the `ask init` command with the `ask configure` command to configure the ASK CLI with your Amazon developer account credentials. See [docs](https://developer.amazon.com/de-DE/docs/alexa/smapi/ask-cli-v1-to-v2-migration-guide.html)